# GSAP Draggable: How to dynamically block movement

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am looking for a way to prevent dragging an object over other objects when using **GSAP** `Draggable`.

An object *A* that is dragged around must be "blocked" by another object *B*, so that *A* cannot overlap *B*.

I know how to detect "hits" with `hitTest`, but how do I prevent the dragged object from being moved over another object?